# Terraform force delete IAM group on destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I have created an IAM group via terraform using the following code snippet. Later I manually assigned users to this group depending on demands – therefore these group associations are managed outside terraform.

```
resource "aws_iam_group" "eks_user" {
  name          = "eks_user"
  path          = "/eks/user/"
  force_destroy = true
}
```

Now I want to delete the group using `terraform destroy` to save costs at the end of the day, but it fails as the group still has users assigned. How can I still delete resources even they have associations?

```
...
module.main.module.vpc.module.vpc.aws_vpc.this[0]: Destruction complete after 0s
module.main.module.eks.module.eks.aws_iam_role.cluster[0]: Destruction complete after 2s
╷
│ Error: Error deleting IAM Group eks_user: DeleteConflict: Cannot delete entity, must remove users from group first.
│       status code: 409, request id: 479d0bfb-b099-4d4a-9753-d1c7601d142e
│
│
╵
```

Comment: You'll need to remove them manually I think.

Comment: If Terraform isn't also creating the users, then it can't handle this delete scenario. You would have to delete the users (or remove them from the group) manually. However your reason for deleting an IAM group (to save costs) isn't really a problem, because IAM groups don't cost anything.

Comment: @lony As per the AWS documentation, To delete the group, it must not contain any users or have any attached policies. But for some reasons, you need to delete the group along with users in terraform, there is no straight forward way you can do other than using `terraform import` and then destroy the users first and then groups.

Comment: Thanks - that's really unfortunate. When I recreate the group – can I enable “reimporting” it as well if it was not deleted properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AWS CLI to remove those users:
`remove-user-from-group`
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/remove-user-from-group.html

And on Terraform you can use a null resource to do the removal when you call destroy,
something like:

```txt
resource "null_resource" "remove_users" {
  depends_on  = ["aws_iam_group.your_group"]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    when    = "destroy"
    command = "aws iam remove-user-from-group --user-name Bob --group-name Admins"
  }
}
```

of course that is a very simple command ...
you probably will need multiple of those removals or a loop to remove all

---

Now if you are exclusively doing this to reduce costs,
you might not need to do this, seem the AWS Groups are free
https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

> Any AWS customer can use IAM. The service is offered at no additional charge. You will be charged only for the use of other AWS services by your users.

Comment: Thanks a lot – did expect something like lifecycle hooks.